# I need an alternative for "her whole life"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, synonyms

In my story a young girl only understands the life of a dancer, but once her dream comes to an end she doesn't know what to do with herself.

I need a better way of saying

> She danced *all day every day*
>   or
>   She danced *her whole life*

Answer (score 3):

How about: " she danced her life away"? OR "danced lifelong"; she is a lifelong dancer.

Comment: +1 not because it really fits here but because this is a wonderfully idiosyncratic construction. I'd say 'her life' _isn't_ best considered a direct object here.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, please explain what you mean by your second sentence.

Comment: Meyer says, in his article [Objects or not – passivisability test etc](http://www.queensu.ca/strathy/blog2012/guest11-12/meyer.html) : 'It seemed counter-intuitive to me, for instance, to class predicates such as _lack courage, weigh 15 kilos, resemble one's aunt, have a sense of humour_ and other non-passivisable structures as being transitive and as involving an object. '

Answer (score 0):

"day in, day out", or just "never stop dancing"

Answer (score 0):

**end-all and be-all**, or  alternatively, **be-all and end-all**

> 1: (idiomatic) something considered to be of the utmost importance; something essential or ultimate.
>
> •  “He thought that cars were the be-all and end-all of life.”
>
> •  “Profit is the be-all and end-all of business.”

or perhaps,

> ***raison d'être*** (plural *raisons d'être* or *raison d'être* or *raison d'êtres*):

The claimed reason for the existence of something or someone; the sole or ultimate purpose of something or someone. (literally "***reason to be***") 
“Surfing became his *raison d’être*.”

As this is a phrase borrowed from the French, it is often written in italics.

See the Wiktionary [**Link**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be-all_and_end-all)

Answer (score -1):

> Twenty-four, seven

Meaning 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.

Answer (score -1):

she danced in her entire life.